# Exclude tests using J2ObjC Gradle Plugin

Tags: java, j2objc, j2objc-gradle

Is it somehow possible to exclude test classes from java-to-ObjcC conversion with `j2objc-gradle` plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The J2ObjC Gradle Plugin can exclude files from both translation and tests. It uses Ant style exclude / include pattern matching on filenames. This is is described in the Gradle documentation with [examples](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:file_trees) and the [PatternFilterable class](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/util/PatternFilterable.html).

As a simple example:

```
j2objcConfig {
    ...
    testPattern {
        // Only run Java unit tests that end with "Test.java"
        include '**/*Test.java'

        // Exclude a single test without needing to specify the full path
        exclude '**/LogTest.java'

        // Exclude all tests within "ignoreDirectory"
        exclude 'ignoreDirectory/**'
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: include '**/*Test.java' does not work in my case, it does not run tests that end with 'Test'